# Not getting all users from the AAD when trying to get user list by using MSGrpah API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

Here is my code which is pulling only 100 users from the active directory. I have granted the "read all user profile permission" in application and delegated sections as well.

```
namespace MVCDemoGraphAPI.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];

        private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];

        private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];

        private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppKey"];

        public async Task<string> Users()

        {
            string authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            AuthenticationResult result = null;

            try
            {
                result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com",
                    new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

            //Now call the Graph API
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

             HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");

            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            string output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Paging filters as described in here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options , 
mainly paging forward.

I recommend to use c# graph client Nuget and then use the code below:

```
  var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
try
    {
        while (users != null)
        {
            var usersList = users.CurrentPage.ToList();
            count = count + usersList.Count();
            users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //
    }
```

Comment: Yeah so the reason is that by default Graph will return 100 users at a time, you gotta request the next pages to get the rest.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response Anass.